# AppWidgetProvider takes resources from wrong package (Lollipop only)

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appwidget, android-5.1.1-lollipop, appwidgetprovider

I have an app widget that shows an image.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + packageName + "/" + resId);
rv = new RemoteViews(defaultPackageName, widgetLayout);
rv.setImageViewUri(R.id.image, uri);
```

Images are stored in different packages under `drawable` directory, i am getting its resource id like so:

```
Resources r = getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication(otherPackage);
int resId = r.getIdentifier("image_1", "drawable", otherPackage);
```

Everything works correctly until the `image_1` is an xml bitmap, that has an `android:src` tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/pat1"
        android:tileMode="repeat"/>
```

After a long research, what i found out and what i have tried:

1. The problem occurs only in lollipop (5.0, 5.1 etc...), and only in AppWidgetProvider (it works correctly if i use this resource inside activity).
2. It is neither working with other methods like:

   ```
   rv.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.image, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(r, resId));
   ```
3. It is getting the right resource id of `@drawable/pat1`, but taking the drawable with the same res id from default package. (I have checked that in `R.java` in both packages) If there is no resource with that id, it just puts nothing inside `R.id.image`, and the widgets appears to be blank.
4. I have tried to hardcode the package name in `image_1.xml` like so:

   ```
   android:src="@com.other.package.name:drawable/pat1"
   ```

   wasn't helpful.
5. The problem occurs on a real devices with different roms and launchers, as well as on an emulator.

I hope i was clear, and hope someone faced similar problem and can share a solution or suggest more workarounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in Lollipop, so i solved that by a workaround.
I just created similar layouts in all my packages, inside each layout there is an ImageView with needed drawable.
Finally i let my RemoteViews create itself from selected layout.

```
RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(otherPackage, layoutResId);
```